# Поиск по строке: в чём ошибка?

Tags: c#

Задача следующая: тут как бы поиск по строке, использую кнопку как "найти далее", однако выделяет всегда только первый. В чём ошибка?

```
string str;
bool flag = false;
int go;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag==false)
    {
        str = form1.textBox1.Text;
        char fs = Convert.ToChar(textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1));
        go = form1.textBox1.Text.IndexOf(fs);
        int len = textBox1.TextLength - 1;
        if (textBox1.Text.Substring(1, len) == form1.textBox1.Text.Substring(go + 1, len))
        {
            form1.textBox1.Select(go, len + 1);
            form1.Focus();
        }
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        str = str.Remove(go, 1);
        char fs = Convert.ToChar(textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1));
        go = str.IndexOf(fs);
        int len = textBox1.TextLength - 1;
        if (textBox1.Text.Substring(1, len) == form1.textBox1.Text.Substring(go + 1, len))
        {
            form1.textBox1.Select(go, len + 1);
            form1.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно кодом, а то что-то не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша главная ошибка: Вы ищите первый символ, а потом сравниваете, что весь текст совпадает. Ищите сразу всю строку целиком. `indexOf` это позволяет. Рекомендую почитать [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7cct0x33.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. И код сразу оптимизировался.